Observing Barracuda VPN client connection issues on Debian 12 with 5.2.2
On a new machine, using same OS and client version, after a fresh system install, I observe from time to time that connection to VPN is broken.
Could be an external issue, but is there a way to log connectivity events/crashes in a local client log?
